# iptables-persistent not uninstalling

Tags: uninstall, iptables

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and I simply want to uninstall iptables-persistent to test something.

As suggested here (http://www.installion.co.uk/ubuntu/saucy/universe/i/iptables-persistent/uninstall.html) I tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove iptables-persistent
```

... but it's still there.  I tried again and got the message:

```
Package 'iptables-persistent' is not installed, so not removed
```

But it isn't removed.  I rebooted and still am able to run

```
/etc/init.d/iptables-persistent save
```

and /etc/init.d/iptables-persistent is still there.  What am I missing?  Shouldn't that file be gone after removing it as I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files in /etc are config files and are kept around when you remove a package in case you reinstall it in the future.  If you want to get rid of them, you have to *purge* the package:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge iptables-persistent
```

Comment: thanks.  what exactly is the purpose of this package?  I added a rule to iptables to ban an ip and it worked.  after reboot the rule was gone.  Isn't this supposed to keep rules after reboot?

Comment: Very late, but since I am looking into this anyway... iptables-persistent snapshots the rules at installation time. If you alter edit your rules, you have to manually update the files in /etc/iptables/